# Issues converting GUID to BCL HI/LO

Tags: c#, grpc, guid, protobuf-net

I am having troubles converting GUIDs to gRPC/protobuf-net bcl-Guids ([bcl.proto with Guid definition](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/Tools/bcl.proto)).

I did find two artilces such as:
[Harmonize protobuf-net bcl.Guid's HI/LO with sql uniqueidentifiers for correlated subquerying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6528583/1099519) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6670210/109951 but it turns out, that those answers are not working correctly for *some* Guids.

So here is my code in .NET Framework 4.7.2:

```
private void SetHighLow(Guid guid)
{
    long[] longs = new long[2];
    byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
    longs[0] = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
    longs[1] = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 8);
    textBoxGuidLo.Text = longs[0].ToString();
    textBoxGuidHi.Text = longs[1].ToString();
}
```

These GUIDs **work fine** for example:

- `63b6ce49-51a6-45b0-8304-cd2b64644419` ➡️ lo: `5021603359597448777`, hi: `1820690530758886531`
- `34fd7e06-6f44-4fc3-925b-472d3c19d677` ➡️ lo: `5747559888192372230`, hi: `8635117081777888146`

These GUIDs result into negative `hi` values and are **not being calculated back correctly**:

- `c0dbb1b2-0a21-40fb-925b-472d3c19d677` ➡️ lo: `4682347377667584434`,hi: `-3098910154901023072`
- `88e052a2-8873-42b8-a62a-e858abef10e5` ➡️ lo: `4807742632017023650`,hi: `-1940787920186627418`

Any ideas?

Comment: they are not simply meant to be ulong? How is the inverse transformation done?

Comment: @JonasH Thank you for pushing me in the right direction, see answer below :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did find the solution, as @JonasH pointed me in the right the direction:

```
private void SetHighLow(Guid guid)
{
    byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
    ulong[] longs = new ulong[2];
    longs[0] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
    longs[1] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8);
    textBoxGuidLo.Text = longs[0].ToString();
    textBoxGuidHi.Text = longs[1].ToString();
    textBoxGuidGrpc.Text = String.Format(HiLoJsonFormat, longs[0], longs[1]);
}
```

Using ToUInt64 instead of ToInt64 did do the trick.

For those looking for the other direction:

```
ulong low = Convert.ToUInt64(textBoxGuidLo.Text);
ulong high = Convert.ToUInt64(textBoxGuidHi.Text);

uint a = (uint)(low >> 32), b = (uint)low, c = (uint)(high >> 32), d = (uint)high;
return new Guid((int)b, (short)a, (short)(a >> 16),
                (byte)d, (byte)(d >> 8), (byte)(d >> 16), (byte)(d >> 24),
                (byte)c, (byte)(c >> 8), (byte)(c >> 16), (byte)(c >> 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want hi and lo values that are UUID(hi, lo) compatible.

```
    using System;
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define the GUID
        Guid guid = new Guid("723ea1a0-c720-4574-a909-95a7c9d83aeb");

        // Convert the GUID to bytes
        byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

   // Print the bytes in hexadecimal format (little-endian)
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes (little-endian):");
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            Console.Write(b.ToString("X2") + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Reverse the byte order for each 8-byte chunk (big-endian)
        ReverseBytes(bytes, 0, 3);
        ReverseBytes(bytes, 4, 5);
        ReverseBytes(bytes, 6, 7);
        ReverseBytes(bytes, 0, 7);
        
        ReverseBytes(bytes, 8, 15);
    

        // Extract most significant bits (high) and least significant bits (low)
        ulong high = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
        ulong low = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8);

        // Print the high and low components
        Console.WriteLine("High: " + high);
        Console.WriteLine("Low: " + low);
    }

    // Helper method to reverse bytes in a byte array for a specified range
      static void ReverseBytes(byte[] bytes, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        while (startIndex < endIndex)
        {
            byte temp = bytes[startIndex];
            bytes[startIndex] = bytes[endIndex];
            bytes[endIndex] = temp;
            startIndex++;
            endIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```